# ways of extracting layers from large Tiff/PSB/PSD files

Tags: tiff, psd, large-data, bigdata

I am having trouble with extracting layers from either super large Tiff/PSB files (about 85+ GB). Any suggestions? I found a couple libraries, but none of them would work with such large files.. Thanks in advance.

---

update 07/31/2013

- psd parser

for **Large PSD** files, you can use this
http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/psdparse

when you compile, you will get an error:

```
  .../psdparse/main.c:326: undefined reference to `rebuild_psd'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [psdparse] Error 1
```

there are a couple .o files are missing.. just find them and compile the missing .o files. Lastly, make sure makefile is good. then you should be good to go.

- tiff parser

for **Large TIFF** files, you can use http://bigtiff.org/
Check the header

```
BigTIFF
0   16-bit  0x4D4D constant
2   16-bit  0x002B version = BigTIFF
4   16-bit  0x0008 bytesize of offsets
6   16-bit  0x0000 constant
8   64-bit  offset to first directory
```

mine was a little different due to big endian and little endian

Comment: Please provide more details. What OS/programming environment? What do you mean by "layers" of TIFF files? Do you have a small sample file available?

Comment: if small psd file, can try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psd-tools

Comment: I can't help with PSD files, but you didn't answer my question. What OS/Programming environment and what do you mean by "layers" in large TIFF files? I wrote my own TIFF library that can handle almost anything. I can possibly provide you with advice/code if you provide more details about the data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: your own TIFF parser,that's really awesome! Big img files in both tiff and psd about 89GB and a couple thousands of tile tiff images. I don't have the offsets to put all the tile images back to a panorama. That's why I would need to extract the layers from the BIG Tiff file. Right now, I use psdparser to parse the big psd file and extract the layers out then use it on tile tiff imgs. This is quick solution for now. I have access to osx,window, and linux. c++ or python or sh script for now on this. Many thanks in advance.  First 16B: 0000000 4949 002a 0008 0000 0017 0100 0004 0001

Comment: Please continue this conversation via email and I can provide more details - bitbank@pobox.com